# Message processing with python AMQP

Tags: python, python-3.x, rabbitmq, amqp, pika

I am working on a rabbitmq consumer application
My consumer should consume and then process the data in a separate thread
I have a script here for that but I cannot make it work. Any help. Thanks so much. It is going to the run function then doing nothing..

```py
import pika, Consumer_Config, queue, threading
import Message_Class

class con:
    def __init__(self):
        self.config = Consumer_Config._config()
        self.path = self.config.path
        self.active = 0
        self.channel = None
        self.tag = None
        self.tb = None

    def channsel(self):
        pika_conn_params = pika.ConnectionParameters(
            host=self.config.url, port=self.config.port,
            credentials=pika.credentials.PlainCredentials(self.config.user_id, self.config.password))
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika_conn_params)
        return connection

    def runq(self, channel, q):
        self.channel = channel

        def read_queue(self):
            queue = self.channel.queue_declare(
                queue="queue", durable=True,
                exclusive=False, auto_delete=False)

            self.channel.queue_bind(
                "queue",
                'exchange',
                routing_key=str('text'))

            self.channel.basic_qos(
                prefetch_count=500)

            self.tag = self.channel.basic_consume("queue", self.on_msg)
            self.channel.start_consuming()

        def on_msg(self, _unused_channel, basic_deliver, properties, body):
            rk = basic_deliver.routing_key
            self.tb = body

            q.put(self.tb)

            self.acknowledge_message(basic_deliver.delivery_tag)

        def acknowledge_message(self, delivery_tag):
            """Acknowledge the message delivery from RabbitMQ by sending a
            Basic.Ack RPC method for the delivery tag.
            """

            # LOGGER.info('Acknowledging message %s', delivery_tag)  # Acknowledgement is done once the message is delivered
            self.channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag)

    def printq(self, q):
        tb = q.get()

        item = Message_Class.Messages().Process_msg(tb, 'text')
        print(item)

    def run(self):
        cn = con()
        connct = cn.channsel()
        channel = connct.channel()

        num_worker_threads = 2
        for i in range(num_worker_threads):
            t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.runq, args=(channel, q))
            t2 = threading.Thread(target=self.printq, args=[q])
            t1.daemon = True
            t2.daemon = True
            t1.start()
            t2.start()
            t1.join()
            t2.join()
        q.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = queue.Queue()
    r = con()
    r.run()
```

Comment: Are you certain there are messages to process in the queue `queue`?

Comment: Hi Thanks for looking into this. Yes. Actually my objective is to use python queue to process the messages separately. So that the main consuming process is fast.